# a "pixelated" picture showing up for some seconds before the actual User Interface loads.

Tags: linux

I have been observing that every time I turn on my *Linux* notebook, I'm seeing a "pixelated" picture showing up for some seconds before the actual User Interface loads.

The thing here is that the very "pixelated" picture is a distorted snapshot of my screen that I watched the previous time I booted my notebook. I hope you understood me as this could affect my privacy. Also, I've observed this on Ubuntu startup and also Apricity OS startup.

Comment: The graphics card memory might just still have the display... if the driver is not clearing it away actively when shutting down, it might sit in the memory until you reboot.

Comment: How can I make it do so?

Comment: This sounds like a hardware problem more then Gnome spying on you.  A pixelated picture would be caused by low system resources or hardware failing.